# Replication for Mirrored server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 3  SQL servers  running SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition, called `A` , `B` and `C`. Server `B` is a mirror of server `A`. There is transactional replication between server `A` and Server `C`.

How can I ensure replication continues to `C` regardless of which server is the primary server in the mirrored pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-PublisherFailoverPartner` option should help you out in your case. I am assuming you want to have replication running irrespective of database running on principal/mirror server.

Below links have your issue covered and has all the details on how to configure it.

http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/dbprogramming/replication-and-mirroring-setup/

https://www.pythian.com/blog/how-to-configure-transactional-replication-mirroring-failover/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151799.aspx

Test it out in your test environment before implementing it on PROD.